# For a project I made 2 arrays, char[] and int[], they are the same size and I want the console to return a response

Tags: c#, arrays

The objective is to return a binary value from the user input. in my mind, I thought that making an array or for loop that reads the response then chooses a corresponding index value and types the value into the console. With this, I get "Index was outside the bounds of the array". Help would be appreciated.

```
char[] letters = {'a','b','c',};

int[] binary = new int[26];
{
binary[0] = 01100001;
binary[1] = 01100010;
binary[2] = 01100011;
}

Console.WriteLine("Tell Me Something");

string sentence = Console.ReadLine();

int[,]outPut = new int[3,letters.Length];

for(int a = 0; a < outPut.Length;a++)

{
outPut[0,a] = binary[a];

Console.Write(outPut);
```

Comment: Debug and see what `outPut.Length` is.

Comment: *"they are the same size"*, no, they are not, you declared the `int` array with a size of 26. Declare it as `byte[] binary = new {  0b0110_0001,  0b0110_0010,  0b0110_0011 };`, as you did with the chars.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop should be

```
for(int a = 0; a < letters.Length;a++)
```

The length of outPut array will be 9 as it is a 2D array.
You are looping from 0-8 and trying to assign it to outPut.
But outPut can only accept 3 numbers in the first row.
That is the reason you are getting the error